# Display Image in MVC5 Using path from DB

Tags: image, list, asp.net-mvc-4

I am passing a list of strings (part of a relative path from the db) and then iterate over the list to generate the image from the combined string using @Url.Content(); however, I continue to get the error message:

> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'ImagePath' and no extension method 'ImagePath' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Is there a missing reference or using directive required?

```
@model List<String>


@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/Content/{0}", item.ImagePath))">
    </td>
</tr>
```

}

Comment: Your model is a list of strings.  you are iterating over that list with foreach, thus item is a string.  You are trying to reference a property called ImagePath on item, which as I just said is a string... There is no property called ImagePath in the string class... so.. yeah, the compiler is right.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimesin you just get lost in your own changes. After changing from the original IEnumerable into a simple List of strings, I didn't recognize that "item.ImagePath" no longer existed. Hence the answer is to simply use "item" as follows:

```
<img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/Content/{0}", item))">
```